# Laravel 4 - Storing unlimited filenames + image sizes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Im in the middle of writing migrations for a project, im a bit of a newb.

What i want to be able to do is store a gallery on each row of a table.

I have the following fields.

```
id
imagecount
displayimage
timestamps
```

The question i have is .... How would i be able to store varying amounts of imagenames + the sizes of those images in a field.

As im not going to be able to know how many images are in each gallery i have to be able to store varying amounts on the fly.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store images in **single table** then you have to use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). In JSON you can have varying amount of images as separated indexs.

Although you have to spend more coding effort to add or remove images from gallery

Other solution would be to use a **2-table** based approach. Where you need table structure like this

```
Gallery <id,added , other stuff ..>
Images <id,gallery_id,name,size, other stuff ..>
```

Its really straightforward. Store images in `Images` table.Link them using [Primary-Foreign-Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) relation with `Gallery` table.

Comment: Ahhh i didnt think of that ... Thank you :) ... Now to rewrite everything